# For loop to extract object from structures of different lengths

Tags: matlab

I have a .mat file with a 1x200 structure (corresponding to 200 experimental sessions). In each of these cells there is a matrix of different lengths (made up of 600-800 1x1 structures, corresponding to the number of trials in each session). Within each of these structures (trials) there are single values which I wish to store separately. How should I go about this?

allData <1x200 struct> (All sessions)

allData(1,1) <1x1 struct> (1 session)

allData(1,1).trial <600-800x1 struct> (All trials in 1 session, # of trials is variable)

allData(1,1).trial(1,1).value   (What I want to store)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the main 1x200 dataset a _cell_ array or a _structure_ array? What does "a structure of different lengths" mean? Is is also a structure array or just a matrix? Please elaborate on how your data is stored, and if possible, visualize it with MATLAB pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a nested loop:

```
OUTPUT = [];

for I=1:size(allData,2)
   for J=1:size(allData(1,I).trial,1)
      OUTPUT(end+1) = allData(1,I).trial(J,1).value;
   end
end
```

Additional explanations:
When using the `size` function in Matlab `for`-loop statements, it is important to check (if necessary in the debug mode) that the correct dimension is selected. That is why, based on the data format in question here, it says `size(X,2)` first, because it is a `1x200` structure, so we are interested in the 2nd dimension; and `size(Y,1)` second, because it is a `600x1` structure.
As the overall dimension of `OUTPUT` may be difficult to determine a priori, it is initialized as empty vector. This is important for the `(end+1)` 'counter' to work, which will fail, if the variable isn't know when the command is called first. Thereafter, it will simply append the `value` to `OUTPUT`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I still get the same error message as before. "???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same."

Comment: for i = 1:numel(allData)

    nTrials{i} = numel(allData(1,i).trial)

end

for i=1:numel(allData)

   for j = 1: nTrials{i}

      values = allData(1,i).trial(j,1).value;

   end

end

Comment: For the nested loop. When I do "values(end+1)" I get "??? In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same." When I do just "values" I get an empty vector.

Comment: Yes, same issue. The value is a <1 x 1 int>.

Comment: It may very well be the case that some entries are empty, yes.